# how do I force a CNAME to a specific folder in Azure?

Tags: azure

I have a domain, abc.com hosted by xyz hosting. I'm using a CNAME to point the subdomain, games.abc.com to my Azure website, website.azurewebsites.net. Everything at this point is working fine.

In the above scenario. how do I direct a subdomain to a specific folder of an Azure website? For example, stapler.abc.com should point to website.azurewebsites.net/someFolder.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far As I know this is not possible with a CNAME record as you can only point to a record.

However Azure does offer a $root container which you can use.

See [the azure documentation about the root container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee395424.aspx)

A downside to this is that you can't have any names with a '/' in the $root container meaning that if you did want to model a hierarchical approach you would have to make every folder in the root its own container (kind of a pain but do able).

Another downside is that azure doesn't provide a default blob for a container (as far as i know).
Meaning you can't direct somebody to `blob.azurewebsites.net/someFolder` but to a particular file `blob.azurewebsites.net/someFile`